What is the purpose of the argument in eMMC CMD sequence?
To change the bus width sequence for EMMC, I found that ACMD6 sets the bus width from 1bit to 4bit bus.
I thought that I just need a sequence like CMD55-ACMD6.
But I came across an argument are implemented in CMD before like Argument(0)-CMD55- then Argument(1)-ACMD6.
From here I want to know why the Argument(0) and Argument(1) are needed into the CMD sequence?

CMD55 already has an argument of 0b00000000 and a CRC (can be anything tho).

The commands such as ACMD6 are commands that need parameters, also called arguments.
With ACMD6 command to select bus width from the available choices, you need to provide a parameter/argument to select which bus width you want to select.
